# Total Commander slow copying to USB external drives

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, total-commander

Total Commander 7.55a is a lot slower than Windows Explorer when copying files (most visible with big files) to an external USB drive (18MB/s versus 28MB/s).

I've already tried:

- disabling anti-virus
- disabling plugins

What can I do to speed it up?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have enabled the Total Commander copy style. That copies each file one-by-one, this is a very usefull feature if some files allready exist. Windows (at least up to XP) only let you overwrite or cancel the whole copy at once. TC allows you to skip/overwrite on a per-file basis.
You can disable this copy style on the Options page

Comment: That's exactly why I need TC copy style. Also, it seems to be slower than the previous versions of TC itself :( During copy (to/from USB drives or network shares) I can see TC parsing the list of files in the pane, one by one, at a rate of about 2-3 lines per second (parsing = some sort of short flash of the line).

Comment: @alexandrul: Then it seems that you're reporting a suspected bug.  The best place for that is the [Total Commander forum](http://www.ghisler.ch/board/index.php?language=english).  Have you tried posting there also?

Comment: @AKE at that time there were several topics related to USB drives, but the existing answers didn't improve my case. In time I have learned to live with the issue :D

Answer (score 1):

Then try [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php)

Comment: Not an option, sorry.